# Check conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my select query. I have 4 conditions to check this query.

```
$subject // This condition is always true that mean it has a value when executing the query
$option // This condition is also true that mean it has a value when executing the query
$district // Maybe this is true or not
$city // Maybe this is true or not
```

Now I need to make select query with with these 4 conditions.

Can I know is there any way to add these 4 conditions to my WHERE clause and then check which are true or not and then return records according to the condition that query met.

Hope someone will help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You need basics concepts about SQL http://www.sqlcourse.com/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure - connect them with `AND` or `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM .. WHERE subject=? AND ...
```

Hope, you escape the input(PDO do this job for you, if you use prepared statements)

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
WHERE   $subject = 1 AND
        $option = 1 AND
        $district IN (0,1) AND
        $city IN (0,1)
```

Comment: How this work - $district IN (0,1) AND
        $city IN (0,1)

Comment: when executing the query, $district and $city may be false. If those are true the result should come the that values.

Comment: `$district IN (0,1)` is the same as `($district = 0 OR $district = 1)`